# Status of "What theological teachings of Watchman Nee, Witness Lee, and the Local Churches differ from Reformed Theology"

Tags: discussion

I recently updated this question: [What theological teachings of Watchman Nee, Witness Lee, and the Local Churches differ from Reformed Theology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32587/what-theological-teachings-of-watchman-nee-witness-lee-and-the-local-churches). I'm wondering if this would be a good time to examine the "on-hold" status of the question. (And if it's still on-hold, please let me know how I can improve it.)

Thanks!

Comment: Remember you already have [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/32582/6071) asking if they're reformed.

Comment: @curiousdannii I didn't realize that was a separate question. I thought it was the same one, just expanded. I've closed one as a duplicate pending some further clarification on how those two actually differ. It seems to be I'd be giving the same answer to both.

Comment: @curiousdannii : good call, I forgot about the duplicate question. Thanks for closing it / marking it as duplicate. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's still not a great question because there are a wide spectrum of differences that could be mentioned and it's not clear what sort of differences you are looking for, put the extra background does make it easier for an expert to make a stab at it so I have gone ahead and voted to reopen it.